# Counter-Example for Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've been doing some reading about the Radon-Nikodym theorem and I came across some counter-examples when the assumption of $\sigma$-finiteness isn't met (most of which were pretty trivial choices of measures). I also came across the following exercise which I haven't managed to solve:

Let $\mu$
  be the restriction of the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure $\lambda_{2}$
  to the $\sigma$-algebra $$\mathcal{F}:=\left\{ A\times\mathbb{R}\ |\ A\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\right\} \subseteq\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)$$It is easy to see that $\left(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$ is not $\sigma$-finite. Now Define $\nu:\mathcal{F}\to\left[0,\infty\right)$
  by $\nu\left(A\times\mathbb{R}\right)=\lambda_{2}\left(A\times\left(0,1\right)\right)$
 . Note that for any $A\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$
  one has $$\mu\left(A\times\mathbb{R}\right)=\lambda_{2}\left(A\times\mathbb{R}\right)\geq\lambda_{2}\left(A\times\left(0,1\right)\right)=\nu\left(A\times\mathbb{R}\right)$$
Which obviously shows that $\nu\ll\mu$. The exercise is to show that there is no density of $\nu$ w.r.t to $\mu$, obviously this would involve assuming such a density exists and reaching some contradiction but I haven't managed to do that.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $\mu$ takes only two values: $\{0,\infty\}$.
2. Suppose $f$ is a density (positive, measurable). Since $\nu$ is not identically zero, there exist $n$ such that $\mu(f^{-1}([\frac 1n,\infty])>0$. However by continuity with respect to increasing limits, this means that for some (possibly larger) $n$, $\mu(f^{-1}[\frac 1n,\infty])\cap [-n,n]\times {\mathbb R})>0$. Therefore this measure is infinite.
3. Now complete:

$$\begin{align*}  2n &\ge  \nu( f^{-1}([\frac 1n,\infty])\cap [-n,n]\times {\mathbb R}) \\
&= \int_{f^{-1}([\frac 1n,\infty])\cap [-n,n]\times {\mathbb R}} f d \mu\\
&  \ge \frac 1n \mu(f^{-1}([\frac 1n,\infty])\cap [-n,n]\times {\mathbb R}) = \frac 1n \times \infty.
\end{align*}$$

Contradiction.